# Why is my pizza doughy inside?

Tags: oven, pizza

If my pizza comes out perfectly baked on the upper and lower sides but still doughy in the inside, what mistake am I making? I use a gas oven set at 240 degrees celsius. I also knead it for 10 minutes and do not overload it with toppings.

Comment: I can think of a few potential issues, could you please give a few more details, e.g. how thick, what kind of oven, pan etc... Welcome to the site!

Comment: And while you at it: posting your recipe wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: How thick did you roll the base out too?

Comment: Recipe: 3 3/4 cups flour - 1/2 tbp instant yeast- 1/4 tsp sugar 1 tbsp olive oil -salt- 1 1/2 cups water.

Comment: the thickness of the base could be around 2 cm.

Comment: The recipe I sue just says pizza, it doesn't say whether it is a deep dish or thin crust one.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things you can try, but the first thing I would start with is weighing your ingredients. Use a recipe that provides ingredients by weight and buy a decent kitchen scale.

Next I would look at your temperature and set that to be as high as your oven will go(mine goes to 550°F).

I would ensure that you aren't over topping. I know you mentioned that you aren't over topping, but I still would "top even less" until you can figure your crust out.

Other general tips that might help depending on your situation:

- Use a steel/stone
- Bring the dough to room temperature
- Thin your dough further
- Par bake the dough before topping
- Proof the dough for longer
- Use room temperature ingredients

Answer (score 1):

Without details, it's a bit of a stab in the dark, but still:

Have you checked your recipe? Some doughs are intended for these paper-thin pizzas, other for deep-dish, almost cakey pizzas. Swap these and your results might be very disappointing.

A few pointers, how to "read" the recipe<sup>1</sup>:

- Deep dish doughs typically have a generous amount of fat (olive oil, lard, shortening, whatever) and sometimes cornmeal while thin crust (for purists) ist flour, water, salt and yeast only (or perhaps a *tiny* bit of oil).
- Dough thickness for deep dish is around 1/2 inch / 1-2 cm, thin crust is, somewhat obviously, about "as thin as you can get it without tearing".
- Deep dish is baked in a pizza pan, while thin crust prefers a pizza stone or steel or, in a pinch, a hot cookie sheet.
- A deep dish needs at least 15-20 minutes, likey 30 or more until done, while a thin crust ideally is done in a few minutes (seconds, in fact, but home ovens don't get hot enough).
- Therefore a deep dish pizza is baked at 425F / 220C (sometimes a tad hotter) while for a thin crust you fire up your oven as high as it will go and use a well-preheated pizza stone to supply consistent heat.

As you write

> perfectly baked on the upper and lower sides but still doughy in the inside

I'll assume you are more on the thick-crust side. So a few suggestions:

- bake a bit longer to ensure the middle is done as well. This might require lowering oven temperature a few degrees to avoid burning the top and bottom.
- Make sure your dough is mature - while the edges usually handle being off quite well, the middle remains soggy or dense. (This is true for bread and other baked goods as well.) As I don't know your method, experiment with *longer* and *shorter* resting times or do some research on how to recognize the different proofing stages.
- Consider par-baking the crust and adding the filling after 10 minutes or so. As toppings are typically already "cooked", this is fine from a food-safety view.
- Another option is to go for a "slightly thinner deep dish pizza".
- Check the hydration of your dough: If you use a high-hydration dough (=lots of liquid in the dough), a pizza pan with tiny holes to let some steam escape *downwards* might be an opion. Or use a *tiny bit* less water.

And as I said, this is a bit of (educated) guessing, based on experience but lacking information.

---

<sup>1</sup> especially the recipes with the nondescript title "Pizza"...

Answer (score 0):

Until you have the recipe banged out; I would start with just a cheese pizza to narrow down the issues.

1. Do not use ingredients that have high moisture content; (vegetables and fruits)
2. Decide on how you want to deal with moisture on bottom of dough; 
   a use a pan with holes in bottom (special pizza pans).
   b.  Douse bottom of pan with olive oil or lard to create an almost FRY environment for bottom of pizza; will keep the bottom of pizza from become moist.
   c.  Pizza stone or baking stones; get it roasting hot at 500+F before using.
3. Be sure oven is properly warmed up before using; I typically have 2 pizza stone @500 degrees; takes oven 1 hour to warm up completely with the stones.